# Good practice for protoss player against MMM in PvT

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Currently, I'm bronze player in US league, I always have a problem in the battle situation with my army against MMM pattern.

My composite army always contain zealot/stalker/sentry(not much)/HT/Archon(sometime)

Sometime, I can use psi storm and feedback on their medivac but I lose the HT sometime because my problem is bad micro in the battle situation like this.

So, my question. Do you have any tips, youtube or practice map to practise? :\

Comment: HTs should focus storming the MM ball not on the medivacs, only feedback them when they are retreating or coming in for a drop

Answer (score 7):

The Terran MMM technique is easily defeated by the [Protoss Deathball](http://www.cheatmasters.com/blog/2011/05/31/starcraft-ii-protoss-strategy-the-deathball-guide/) technique. The Deathball takes advantage of large clusters of weak units which is exactly what MMM is.

Basically, you create a "ball" which consists of:

- Colossi (w/ range upgrade) in the centre, this is the key element
- Stalkers creating a forward arc or ring around the Colossi as a buffer
- Immortals (optional) to provide support against armored targets
- Sentries (optional) for +2 armor and preventing the enemy from spreading out (force field)

Your Colossi target the largest clumps of Marines and Marauders, while keeping them out of range. The stalkers shoot down Medivacs that wander too close and assist with cleaning up Marauders. Immortals are a hard counter to marauders as well if they are more armor focus.

If your opponent uses vikings to attack the Colossi, upgrade your Stalkers with blink - and blink towards the vikings.

This strategy is effective as your Colossi deal more damage than the Medivacs can heal, often using multiple Colossi on the same target to one-hit-kill swaths of Marines and Marauders. The Protoss Death Ball punishes terrans without tanks.

Comment: Without Zealots to tank and force kiting, Terran bio will absolutely shred your composition. It's unrealistically gas heavy for the same reason.

Comment: @Decency disagree completely.

Comment: Alrighty. Would be interested in seeing a VOD of a competitive player utilizing this composition.

Comment: The deathball is the bane of a bio ball, mostly because the colossi can wipe out marines so effectively. The problem lies in that the deathball can only be in one place at a time, so a clever terran will be dropping at your bases as you're trying to form it, and setting traps that can be dangerous to walk into.

Comment: @Sconibulus that's why you need observers spread along the drop paths so you can intercept them

Comment: @Decency If we are trying to answer the question, rather than arguing about balance, a game of *competitive player* is irrelevant. OP is Bronze, so the advice is valid - Colossus-Stalker counters MMM that counters non-Colossus ball.

Comment: @OrcJMR I don't think anyone's said anything about balance. Players should try to use a proper composition in games regardless of skill level. What "proper" means is typically determined by the top players and emulated below.

Comment: @Decency Please create a competing answer if you think this one is insufficient.

Comment: I dont agree with Immortals in this composition those resources should be spent on more colossus or stalkers. The immortals are far too likely to target the marines.

Comment: @Decency That was an exaggeration. Players should not use a *proper composition* if using it efficiently exceeds their mechanics. Top players, for one, are accounting for many possibilities that do not happen in Bronze, and trying to blindly copy them is suboptimal. Anyway, our argument seems to drift towards a war, so I am willing to listen to your reply and suggest ceasing fire :-)

Comment: +1 my brother and I play 2s a ton and I am Terran, he is Protoss.  When we 1v1 to increase the playability of our builds, whenever I go MMM he creates the death ball and it wins nearly every time.

The fine print to this strategy, however, is tanks and vikings.  If the Terran has a good enough number of vikings and/or tanks, you will still be fighting an uphill battle especially if the Terran player has good micro.

Answer (score 3):

The Answer by Resorath was almost right, but what you want to do in bronze league is always focus on macro above micro.

To this end the protoss death ball should win you most bronze level games against MMM. The difference is that you want to focus on units that don't require as much work on your part. Sentries and high templar require you to use their spells quickly and correctly to get the most out of them. Even immortals require you to target fire armored units. Instead go with units that work well on the attack move command and soak up a bunch of damage.

**Your Composition/upgrades:**

Colossi - you'll want 2-3 at least and the range upgrade

Stalker - don't worry about the blink upgrade

Zealot - do get the charge upgrade

If you can get the +1 armor upgrade do so, it is far better than having +1 attack versus terran.

**Strategy**
This build does require some time in order to build up your colossi and army count. You will want to delay your enemy's attack as long as possible. A mothership core (if you have heart-of-the-swarm) with photon-overcharge on a nexus can halt very early rushes. Some scouting or grabbing of a watch tower can let you know when your enemy is going to move out. I would also recommend trying to counter attack your enemy if he tries to move out before you are ready, but this is more difficult to do at bronze league. If you are finding that you are dying before you can pull this build off try cutting the zealot charge upgrade and armor upgrade. If that is still not giving you enough time try building only zealots to start, using all your gas for colossi and the range upgrade.

Comment: `Stalker - don't worry about the blink upgrade while you are still in bronze` - I would agree if you would have said that Blink Upgrade is not the best choice vs MMM, but saying "Don't bother because you're bronze" is like telling him not to improve at all. Why shouldn't he go for blink if he can halfway decently micro it? Just because he is bronze it doesn't mean he doesn't have any mechanical skill.

Comment: @Toby I agree that a player can and should try to improve, but blink micro shouldn't be first priority in this build. I have edited my answer